# New Delhi, India, town level boundary files for GIS

Tags: data, india

I'm trying to find boundary files for New Delhi to map religious diversity (data here: 
**http://www.censusindia.gov.in/DigitalLibrary/MFTableSeries.aspx**), and I have downloaded the GADM files and tried some other sources mentioned in earlier threads. My data is at the town level and I am looking for a shapefile at the town level for New Delhi. So far, the files I've found do not match the boundaries of the towns/areas listed in the excel sheet.

Can someone help me find the right file?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you need.  Do you need a shapefile for the New Delhi, India boundary or a shapefile that includes each town's boundaries?  I quickly found the New Delhi, India administrative boundary in [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2763541) and the  extracted it with a query in [overpass-turbo.eu](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/acu).  If you need boundaries for the individual towns I altered the [query and found them](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/acv). Just click 'Run' at the top and then you can download your data in a few different ways inclusding shapefile.  Overpasss-turbo is a very powerful and quick way to extract data from the OSM database.

Comment: Hi cbunn! Thanks so much for your reply. What I'm looking to map is the towns in Delhi (column 'area name' in the excel file in the link). I'm not quite sure they are villages (I am new to Delhi's geography and from the codebook for this excel file, I gather they are 'towns'). The map generated from your query seems to be of villages. How do I modify the query to get these town boundaries? Thanks!

Comment: Try searching one of the town names in OpenStreetMap and then under the layers menu on the left select the map data checkbox.  Click on the polygon for the town you searched and it will show you its data.  Then you can modify the query in overpass with the correct tag for these towns.

Comment: Hi again! Some of the names are listed simply as 'locality', others are listed as 'place'. I've tried modifying the code using administrative instead of political and other tags such as locality and place, but I'm still not getting most of the names on that list. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It may be that they are not all in OSM due to their size.

Comment: It may be the case that the towns are so small they don't have distinct boundaries at all and may rely on local knowledge only for territory descriptions.  If this is the case, you could create points for each town, ideally in their center and then create voronoi polygons that would estimate their boundaries.

Comment: Try searching for your towns from the Geonames database.  Download the IN.zip text file and then create a point file from it in your GIS software. http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

Comment: OK, thank you for these suggestions. I will let you knwo how it goes!